# Cannot pass CSS props into Custom DataGrid styled-component using React MUI

Tags: typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I'm trying to pass my `window.innerHeight` value I catch on resize to React Mui's `DataGrid` component.

TS throws an error though when I try passing the value to a reusable function I created.

```
export const CustomDataGridDesign = styled(DataGrid)(({theme, height}) => ({
  minHeight: `${height}`,
  border: 'none',

  "*": {
    scrollbarWidth: 'thin',
    scrollbarColor: 'var(--secondary-color) #d3d9de',
  },
  "*::-webkit-scrollbar": {
    width: 6,
    height: 6,
  },
  "*::-webkit-scrollbar-track": {
    backgroundColor: "#d3d9de",
  },
  "*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb": {
    backgroundColor: "#4f5f71",
    borderRadius: 2.5,
  },
  ...... }));
```

In my CustomStyledComponents.tsx folder I get this error message (@ bottom of post).

It looks like TS isn't factoring the cssProps that they've whitelisted for the `styled()` method i'm importing from `"@mui/material/styles"`

How do I fix this TS error?

Thanks in advance.

```
Property 'height' does not exist on type 'Omit<Partial<DataGridPropsWithDefaultValues> & DataGridPropsWithComplexDefaultValueBeforeProcessing & DataGridPropsWithoutDefaultValue<...>, DataGridForcedPropsKey> & { ...; } & RefAttributes<...> & MUIStyledCommonProps<...> & { ...; }'.ts(2339)
```